# '_' parameter in GET requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, get

I have noticed in several websites recently the '_' parameter which appears to be set to a random string. eg:

```
 stackoverflow.com/?_=12345678
```

What is the purpose of this parameter and how is the number generated?

Comment: Probably to ensure the browser doesn't cache the request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding a random numerical param to requests is a common way to defeat browser caching of AJAX result sets.

Comment: I will add to this that, since the number added is random, the browser detects it as a 'different' request (from previous, similar ones - if any) and it's forced to send the request to the server instead of returning the cached response (if any)